# How to set breakpoints in a library module (pdb)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I am debugging a python script which sys.path looks like

```
sys.path = ['','home/my_library', ..]
```

I'm having troubles to set a breakpoint in a module from `my_library` while using pdb. 
The script imports the library with:

```
import my_library as foo
```

In turn, my_library makes its module(s) available by:

```
from my_module import bar
```

**How can address my_module's code while running pdb on my script?**

PS: I have tried the followings without success:

```
b my_module:1
b my_library.my_module:1
b my_library.bar:1
b foo.my_module:1
b foo.bar:1
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You qualify the breakpoints with the *filename*, not the object name:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import artwork  # module we want to break inside
>>> pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <console>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) b artwork/models.py:1
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/projects/artwork/models.py:1
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980836/2588818).

Comment: ah yes, the point was to put the slash, not the dot! Doh! What we would call a Columbus' egg!! Solution is then `b my_library/my_module`. Thanks a lot :-)