# pdb: set a breakpoint on file which isn't in sys.path

Tags: python, pdb

I'm writing a python package and I want to use pdb to debug it. When I try to set break point in one of the files, I get an error:

```
The specified object 'CaptureManager.frame' is not a function or was not found along sys.path
```

I googled it, and found a solution:

append the directory which contains my file into sys.path

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"project_cameo"))
```

But after few times, I get very annoyed, because I have to do it every time I restart my debug session. Is there a 'smart' way of doing it?

Comment: You could add the `sys.path..` line to your module and it would be loaded automatically

Comment: ok. I put it in __init__.py, it works!, a lot 'smarter' than before, but still looks like a workaround...

Comment: What about `pip install -e .` your lib in a venv?

Comment: this sound like a good idea. I will try it to see if it is a good option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load your module in order to use it (debug it in your case).
Python looks at `sys.path` variable to load it's modules.

From the docs,

> **sys.path**:
>   A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

It is initialized from the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable; so you can add your path to this env variable instead of your module.

Or you can add the `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"project_cameo"))` line to your module at the top.

Comment: I will try change the PYTHONPATH to see if it's convenient. but I prefer not to  change my source code for debugging.

Comment: @scotthuang let me know if that helped

Comment: yes. It helps. I think the conclusion is that there is no 'native' way of doing this, but we can do it  by modifying os.path. But I think there is a possibility that we will mess up the normal search path by doing that. It is ok for debugging, but it's something I need keep in mind when I do that.

Comment: @scotthuang you can add the path to the end of the sys.path, and you will just extend it, won't mess anything. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it, thanks

Answer (score 9):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071175/how-to-set-breakpoints-in-a-library-module-pdb) you can also set a break point by writing the full path to filename (or path relative to directory on `sys.path`)

For example

```
b /path/to/module.py:34
> Breakpoint 1 at /path/to/module.py:34
```