# Adding breakpoint in pdb results with "End of file"?

Tags: python, breakpoints, pdb

I'm so tired of this ...

Well, [pdb: set a breakpoint on file which isn't in sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317180/pdb-set-a-breakpoint-on-file-which-isnt-in-sys-path) says:

> According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071175/how-to-set-breakpoints-in-a-library-module-pdb) you can also set a break point by writing the full path to filename

And I've even tried it once before, and it worked.

And now I'm trying to debug another script:

```
$ python3 -m pdb freeze.py
> c:/tmp/mytest/freeze.py(9)<module>()
-> import py2exe
(Pdb) n
> c:/tmp/mytest/freeze.py(10)<module>()
-> from py2exe import freeze
(Pdb) b /mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py:166
End of file
(Pdb) b
(Pdb)
```

And just to show that file, and line 166, exists:

```
$ awk 'NR >= 165 && NR <= 167 {printf "%d\t%s\n", NR, $0}' /mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py
165         def analyze(self):
166             logger.info("Analyzing the code")
167
```

What is the problem? Why cannot I set a breakpoint and I get "End of file" instead? How do I set the breakpoint properly so it works?

Answer (score 1):

Right, found that error message here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a50cf6c/Lib/pdb.py#L1084 :

```python
...
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, globs)
        if not line:
            self.message('End of file')
            return 0
...
```

... so the problem is with `linecache.getline`.

Now, here I am using the MINGW64 Python3 under Windows 10; MINGW64 `bash` shell typically accepts linux-style paths - but it turns out, Python3 (or at least `linecache`) does not - from withn `pdb`:

```
(Pdb) import linecache
(Pdb) linecache.getline("/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py", 166, None)
''
(Pdb) linecache.getline("C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py", 166, None)
'        logger.info("Analyzing the code")\n'
```

So, apparently I needed to specify the full path with a Windows drive prefix (`C:`), just the Linux-style full path does not work:

```
(Pdb) b C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py:166
Breakpoint 1 at c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2exe/runtime.py:166
```

Now, there remains the problem that the breakpoint does *not* hit even though I see the output of the corresponding line ("Analyzing the code") printed - but that is another issue ...