# Moviepy OSError Exec format error - Missing Shebang?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, moviepy

I am attempting to use MoviePy with Python 3.2.3 on Raspian.
I have installed it (for Python 2.7, 3.2 and 3.5... long story) and the line

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

works fine.
When I try

```
clip = VideoFileClip("vid.mov")
```

which is the most basic command, it gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/QuickFlicsPics/moviepytest.py", line 8, in <module>
  clip = VideoFileClip("vid.mov")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/distpackages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 55, in __init__
  reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 32, in __init__
   infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 237, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
  proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 745, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1371, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)

OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I have researched this error, and it appears to be something to do with a shebang line missing somewhere. Is this correct, if so, how do I go about finding where it is missing, and what do I add?
Thanks

Edit:
As per cxw's comment, I installed moviepy using the command

```
pip-3.2 install moviepy
```

(I may have used 'sudo' as well)

FFMPEG was supposed to download automatically when I first used moviepy:

> MoviePy depends on the software FFMPEG for video reading and writing. > You don’t need to worry about that, as FFMPEG should be automatically > downloaded/installed by ImageIO during your first use of MoviePy (it takes a few seconds). If you want to use a specific version of FFMPEG, follow the instructions in file config_defaults.py.

[Quote from installation guide [here](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html)]

Comment: What are the `cmd` and the `popen_params` in the `sp.Popen` call?  If you don't know, you can run `python -m pdb -c "b /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py:237" -c c your_script.py` per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33808301/2877364), then `p cmd` and `p popen_params` at the pdb prompt when you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: It might not be a shebang at all - it might be binaries compiled for the wrong architecture ;) .  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40004639/edit) to include the commands you used to install moviepy and ffmpeg.

Comment: @cxw Your command gave the 'Error: -c does not exist'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!  Should be in pdb 3.2 per the linked answer - I just pulled it from there and haven't tried it myself :) .  Oh - I should have said `python3` rather than `python`.  Or else do `python3 -m pdb your_script.py` and then enter the `b` and `c` commands at the pdb prompt.

Comment: I tried the your updated commands, no luck, but I'm not sure they're needed now.

Comment: I have installed FFMPEG with 'sudo apt-get install ffmpeg'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually download ffmpeg, then before running your Python code, do

```
export FFMPEG_BINARY=path/to/ffmpeg
```

at the shell/terminal prompt.

As far as I can tell from [the source](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py#L48), the automatic download of ffmpeg does not know about Raspberry Pis.  The [auto-download code](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/core/fetching.py#L29) pulls from [the imageio github repo](https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/tree/master/ffmpeg), which only knows "linux32" vs. "linux64".  It doesn't look like it has an ARM-linux option.  When the ARM kernel sees a non-ARM image, it throws the error you see.

Rather than using the environment variable, you can edit your moviepy [`config-defaults.py`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/config_defaults.py) file to specify `FFMPEG_BINARY = r"/path/to/ffmpeg"`.

**Edit** to find the `path/to/ffmpeg` after installing it with `apt-get`, do

```
dpkg -L ffmpeg | grep bin
```

at the shell/terminal prompt.  It will probably be in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and will probably be called `ffmpeg` or `ffmpeg-x.xx` (with some version number).
<sub>Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/129024) for `dpkg`</sub>

Comment: I have installed FFMPEG with 'suso apt-get install ffmpeg'. Where is the "shell prompt" is that the terminal?

Comment: I've put it in the terminal, nothing (good or bad) happened. When I ran the program, I got the error:

Comment: I got the error: 'IOError [...] file might be corrupted [...] might be using a deprecated version of FFMPEG [...] On Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website'. Seems fairly self explanatory and is the most helpful error message I have ever seen :)

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I had been trying to fix this for a week! After the apt-get ffmpeg install didn't work, I followed [these](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2016/03/ffmpeg-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/) instructions to the letter, and all the issues were immediately solved.

Comment: @Gloin fantastic!  Glad to be able to help.