# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error while reading video Moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, video-processing, moviepy, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to run a video processing code on NVIDIA TX2 using `moviepy`. The code is:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(video_file)
video_clip = clip.fl_image(process_vid)
video_clip.write_videofile(output_vid2)
```

I get the error in the first line. The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "img_test.py", line 117, in <module>
    clip = VideoFileClip(video_file)   
File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 91, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)   
File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 33, in __init__
    fps_source)   
File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 256, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) 
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I even used the refernce of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004639/moviepy-oserror-exec-format-error-missing-shebang) but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?