# Python Debugger (pdb): Navigating through multi-module code using pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I have a code separated into three modules; the modules are the following: 
1) run_module.py
2) module1.py
3) module2.py

I have an if **name** == '**main**': statement inside run_module.py and I am very comfortable using my CLI to do python -b pdb run_module.py and then set a breakpoint inside run_module.py using the (pdb) b linenumber format.

My question is this: How can I set breakpoints inside module1.py or module2.py from the CLI; ie. not intervening directly into the module1.py and module2.py scripts and typing import pdb; pdb.set_trace()?

Any insight would be extremely appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simpler way to put PDB breakpoints in Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980749/simpler-way-to-put-pdb-breakpoints-in-python-code)

Comment: I saw that post and no, it does not help; I tried it out and I got the following: ***The specified object [filename] is not a function or was not found along sys.path. *** I found a post also addressing this case, that didn't work for me either. I feel like I am missing smth obvious. Thoughts? Do you need anything else from me to get me an answer?

Comment: Can you add the file structure to your question?

Answer (score 2):

`pdb`, like `gdb`, or [trepan3k](https://python3-trepan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has a break command:

```
(Pdb) help break
b(reak) ([file:]lineno | function) [, condition]
With a line number argument, set a break there in the current
file.  With a function name, set a break at first executable line
of that function.  Without argument, list all breaks.  If a second
argument is present, it is a string specifying an expression
which must evaluate to true before the breakpoint is honored.
    
The line number may be prefixed with a filename and a colon,
to specify a breakpoint in another file (probably one that
hasn't been loaded yet).  The file is searched for on sys.path;
the .py suffix may be omitted.
```

But when you do this there are some things you should be aware of.

If you specify breakpoints by filename and line number, it is possible to get a error message. For example:

```
(Pdb) break foo.py
*** The specified object 'foo.py' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.
```

Let's try to understand what the message says. `foo.py` clearly isn't a function. It is a file. Is it in `sys.path`?

```
(Pdb) import sys
(Pdb) sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.6', ...]
```

No. Ok. well how about if I give the file name as an *absolute* path?

```
(Pdb) break /tmp/bug.py:2
Breakpoint 1 at /tmp/bug.py:2
```

Ok. That works. But again there is a caveat: is it *possible* to stop at at that line in that file?  Watch this:

```
(Pdb) break /etc/hosts:1
Breakpoint 2 at /etc/hosts:1
```

`/etc/hosts` is a file, but it is not a Python program. And while as we saw before `pdb` warns if the file is missing, it doesn't check whether the file is a Python file.

If instead you run this with `trepan3k` it prints out a nasty traceback (which I'll fix at some point), but at least it gives some inkling that something is wrong:

```
(Nasty traceback)...
ValueError: path /etc/hosts must point to a Python source that can be compiled, or Python bytecode (.pyc, .pyo)
```

[The traceback has been removed in the github source and will not appear in version 1.2.9. In version 1.2.8 of trepan2 this is gone too.]

Also `pdb` isn't that smart about knowing whether line 2 has code that can be stopped at; `pdb` will warn about empty or blank lines or lines comment lines, but anything more sophisticated than that, like some random text, and no dice.

Again trepan3k is a little better about this:

```
(trepan3k) break /tmp/bug.py:2
** File /tmp/bug.py is not stoppable at line 2.
```

The last caveat when working with breakpoints is that a breakpoint might not be hit because the code never gets there. But you have this also with `sys.set_trace()` so I imagine that kind of behavior is less of a surprise.

One other difference of note between the breakpoints of `trepan3k` and `pdb`. In `pdb` when you breakpoint on a function, you are really setting breakpoint on the first line recorded for that function. That is, you have already entered the function.

In trepan3k you are setting it on the function *call* which is independent of where it is located. Note the different syntax for functions, they have trailing parenthesis after the name, e.g. `foo()` vs `foo`.
A method name given in the context of the object is is a method of is also possible, and I use that a lot. Here is an example:

```
trepan3k /tmp/pathtest.py
(/tmp/pathtest.py:1): <module>
-> 1 from pathlib import Path
(trepan3k) n
(/tmp/pathtest.py:2 @12): <module>
-- 2 mypath = Path(__file__)
(trepan3k) n
(/tmp/pathtest.py:3 @20): <module>
-- 3 print(mypath.match("p.*"))
(trepan3k) break mypath.match()
Breakpoint 1 set at line 972 of file /home/test/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py
(trepan3k) c
(/home/test/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py:972): match
xx 972     def match(self, path_pattern):
(trepan3k) path_pattern
'p.*'
(trepan3k) info pc
PC offset is -1.
```